# Filter data from dropdown list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a long **dropdown** list where I used **Slim Scroller** which is working fine.Now, I want to filter result from drop down list too. 
Anybody suggest me what should I need to do ?

Comment: i want to search data from dropdown list (Select box)

Comment: **Anybody suggest me what should i need to do ?** - Yes.  Post relevant HTML and Javascript, fully explaining what you have tried and what went wrong so that we can help you *fix* your code, not write it for you.

Comment: @Hitu Bansal do you want to filter data from dropdown using a textbox?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis. yes i need this

Comment: @Hitu Bansal you can try something like this https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: @Hitu Bansal is it possible for you to mark, if i post it as an answer?

Comment: Do not post a link as an answer.  What happens when the URL is no longer valid?  This site is meant to be self contained so you will need code to show the solution, preferably with a working example.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis : Sure i will mark .. it may be help someone

Comment: ok thanks i will post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Choosen Jquery Plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to create a search in dropdownlist.

> HTML

```
 <select data-placeholder="Choose a country..." style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select">
```

> Jquery

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});
```

Hope this helps.